# How to generate Null or int in a column?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need to fill null or int randomly in an int field.

How ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, this may be a partial answer but...

```
SELECT CASE WHEN RAND() > 0.5 THEN 'YourInt' ELSE NULL END
```

Will give you either 'YouInt' or NULL based on a random value.

You could then perform an INSERT like this...

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT CASE WHEN RAND() > 0.5 THEN 'YourInt' ELSE NULL END
```

Or, of course an UPDATE

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyField = CASE WHEN RAND() > 0.5 THEN 'YourInt' ELSE NULL END
WHERE MyCondition = MyCriteria
```

But it does not generate an INT for you. Do you already have some INT's somewhere or do you need to generate them?